# What does it mean (given that $M$ is an R-module), that $M=0$? That it is a module generated by the zero of ring $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, notation, modules

I've seen this kind of notation in the context of Nakayama's Lemma, but I don't get it if this means that M is a module generated by R's zero, or if this means that M is simply the empty set?

Comment: The empty set is *never a module*. If $M=0$, then $M$ is the null module, ie $M=\{0\}$ with trivial addition and multiplication by $R$.

Comment: If $M$ is an $R$-module, the equation $M=0$ means that $M$ is a singleton set $\{*\}$ with the operations $*+* := *$ and $r \cdot * = *$ for all $r \in R$. Note that, in that case, $0_M = *$, and that for any other $R$-module $N$, there are unique homomorphisms $M \to N$ and $N \to M$.

Comment: Another wording of the same comment: Every module $M$ has a zero element. If that's the only element in $M$, then one says $M=0$ (because we're too lazy to write $M=\{0\}$).